# Set <body> to 100% window height to include fixed div

Tags: html, css, background-image

```
Please see http://jsfiddle.net/muc0mzgt/.
```

The body basically ends before the footer div as the latter is positioned fixed. Problem here is I want to add a page filling background image that would now end where the red line is as it is attached to the body.

Setting the body height to 100vh gets me already close, but you still can scroll a bit so you see a part of the page without the bg image.

Any ideas?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Post your code in your question. An example that shows the issue would also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a reset.css and then make the `body` & `html` elements 100% height

```css
* { /* quick reset */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Some Paragraph</p>
  <div id="footer">This is some footer text</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Paulie for your reply — that solves the problem!